# The set of $K$ quasiconformal mappings between between the disc fixing the origin is compact

Tags: sobolev-spaces, uniform-convergence, weak-derivatives, quasiconformal-maps

Hubbard page 131 gives

> Corollary 4.4.3 Denote by $\mathcal F_K(\mathbb D)$ the set of $K$-quasiconformal home­omorphisms $f : \mathbb D \rightarrow \mathbb D$ with $f(0)=0$. Then $\mathcal F_K(\mathbb D)$ is compact for the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets.

The proof proceeds as follows:

> [Proof part 1] By equicontinuity of $\mathcal F_K(\mathbb D)$ and Arzela-Ascoli, establish that the closure of $\mathcal F_K(\mathbb D)$ in the set of continuous mappings is compact in the uniform topology. Further establish all limits are homeomorphisms.

It remains to establish that the limit functions are $K$-quasiconformal. **This is where I am stuck.** A priori there is no reason to expect the limit functions to have derivatives in $L^2_\text{loc}$. And even if the limit functions have derivatives in $L^2_\text{loc}$, why should we expect
$$ \left |\frac{\partial f_\infty}{\partial \bar z}\right | \leq k\left |\frac{\partial f_\infty}{\partial  z}\right |?$$

Hubbard says:

> all limits are in $C \mathcal H^1(\mathbb D)$ , since
> $$ \int_{\mathbb D} \left\lVert{[Df]}\right\rVert^2\leq K \int_{\mathbb D} \text{Jac} f=K\pi$$
> so that the distributional derivatives of elements $f \in \mathcal F_K(\mathbb D)$ all lie in a fixed ball of $L^2(\mathbb D)$. Thus their limits (as distributions) do also.

I seem to be confused on if/how Hubbard is relating the values of $\left\lVert{[Df_n]}\right\rVert$ to the value of $\left\lVert{[Df_{\infty}]}\right\rVert$ when all we know is uniform convergence in compact subsets.

---

Also, I presume the stronger conclusion of $\mathcal F_K(\mathbb D)$ is compact in $C\mathcal H^1(\mathbb D)$ is false. That means there might be a sequence $f_n$ such that $f_{n_k}$ converges on compact subsets to a q.c. $f$ but no subsequence of $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $C\mathcal H^1(\mathbb D)$.

Comment: $C\mathcal H^1$ is the space of continuous functions whose partial derivatives are $L^1_\text{loc}$.

Comment: "Hubbard says:..." what they're doing here is getting a uniform $L^2$ bound on $Df_n$. This, together with the pointwise convergence of the $f_n$, gives that the limit $f_\infty$ is in fact in $W^{1,2}$, and $Df_\infty$ satisfies the same $L^2$ bound.

Comment: @Jose27, Thanks, I now understand that the bound implies $f_{\infty}$ has derivatives in $L^2_{\text{loc}}$. Furthermore, $\int_{\mathbb D} \left\lVert{[Df_{\infty}]}\right\rVert^2\leq K\pi$. I am yet to understand why $f_{\infty}$ is $K$-quasiconformal. It seems unlikely to me that the derivatives of $f_n$ converge to the derivatives of $f_{\infty}$. (If we had convergence of derivatives in $L^2$, Hubbard could have mentioned the stronger conclusion of $f_n \rightarrow f_{\infty}$ in the topology of $W^{1,2}$.)